# Limit bandwidth usage (Android/Windows)

Tags: windows, android, wifi

During my last holiday, an overeager podcast app used my entire quota for downloading one podcast.

Now I am looking for apps that will help limit bandwidth usage.

1. Primarily I would like to monitor and limit usage by apps (getting warnings,throttling and blocking  apps).
2. Something up/down can be treaded separately (like photo backups)
3. I probably have a lot of apps that I can't monitor individually, I think I should be notified about those using resources, and then be able to set limits.
4. Would like the possibility of several different "policies", with automatic or manual selection. (I often use a mobile hotspot, so basing it on wi-fi or mobile data is not sufficient).  Can be home operator, roaming status/location, Hotspot name.
5. Sometimes the problem is hotspot clients of my device.  Some granular control would be best.
6. Perhaps granular control of browses - possibility to control websites, tabs perhaps by limiting heavy downloads like flash and photos.
7. Limit bandwidth used by ads.

Comment: Android or Windows?

Comment: Both.  Android phones, and Windows PCs.

Comment: Created an Android-spesific question:

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86563/how-to-control-bandwidth-usage